# Error on vscode terminal using fastapi server with postman

Tags: python, postman, fastapi

I am studying a YouTube video on Fast API with Python and Postman

> (fastapienv) Rodrigos-Air:Youtube_FastAPI rgpalma$ uvicorn main:app
> INFO:     Started server process [14735]
> INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
> INFO:     Application startup complete.
> ERROR:    [Errno 48] error while attempting to bind on address
> ('127.0.0.1', 8000): address already in use
> INFO:     Waiting for application shutdown.
> INFO:     Application shutdown complete.

I got stuck.
Any help? Beginner friendly please.

The error won't correct.

Answer (score 1):

The important part of the error is this line:

```
ERROR:    [Errno 48] error while attempting to bind on address ('127.0.0.1', 8000): address already in use
```

This means you already have a process that's listening on port 8000 (possibly an older instance of your application you didn't kill?).
You could try to kill the process listening on this port (the details vary according to the operating system you're using), or, if it's meant to be used by something you don't want to kill, change the port your application tries to listen to.

Comment: Well thank you but that leeds me to my next question. how do I do that?